# WSO2 APIM: Merge multiple SOAP WSDLs

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a different number of services that have specific WSDLs, although we wanted to merge them into a single one, are we able to do that?

To clarify the question we will provide an example of a backend:

```
http://mytest.ws.com/resource/v2/service.asmx
http://mytest.ws.com/resource/v2/service.asmx?wsdl

http://mytest.ws.com/resource/v2/service2.asmx
http://mytest.ws.com/resource/v2/service2.asmx?wsdl
```

What we are trying to achieve is to join these services in a single base resource, such as:

```
http://mywso2apim.com/resource/v2/service.asmx
http://mywso2apim.com/resource/v2/service2.asmx
```

Is this possible to achieve via WSO2 API Manager?

Thanks for your time!